# Access a committed Kaggle kernel while its running

Tags: python, docker, kaggle

I'm trying to access a committed Kaggle kernel while its running as I want to monitor the execution of my Python code while its running.
I tried to spawn a new python process to collect logs. But the Kaggle docker container doesn't allow to run multiple processes. Is there a way to get around this?